# How can I get the system time in fractional seconds in Perl?

Tags: perl

What is the Perl equivalent of Python's `time.time()`, which returns the system time in fractional seconds?

Answer (score 11):

`Time::HiRes::time()` is the equivalent.  If you don't need partial seconds, you can simply use `time()`, though.

Answer (score 1):

This will help you to resolve your problem

```
$a = time();  
print ("$a\n");
```

Comment: Perl's built-in `time` returns whole seconds, not fractional seconds like Python's `time.time()` does.